# How can I find a specific character + a number in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace all pip that are followed by a number. Example: |2019 (2019 is an example, it is not standard). I have others pip like |note that I do not want them too be replaced.

To find numbers I know that I should use in Regex [0-9] but I can´t combine it with a pip.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to replace `|10abc`, too? Or should only *years* be taken into account?

Comment: Try `\|(?=\d)` to replace with what you need.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56832432/372239) and add some examples with expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Since `|` is an operator for regular expressions, you have to escape it.

Use this:

`\|[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

to replace `|2019` with `(2019` where 2019 is any random number, search for `\|(\d+)` and replace it with `\($1` with `Search Mode: Regular Expression`